# Writing to a disk without syscall

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I am trying to understand how ring 3 to ring 0 transfer works in operating systems.

I think I understand how a syscall works.

My understanding is that when user mode program wants to make a syscall it will setup the call arguments and send an INT that will transfer over control to the OS which will then read the args, do that work and then return control back to user program. There Are more optimized sys enter arms sys exit variants as well.

All this makes sense to me If the user voluntarily calls the syscall.

However, to gurarantee safety OS cannot assume that callers will use syscall to access resources.

My question is — what happens if user program directly tries to access resource (disk) directly without involving OS.

How does the OS intercept it?

Comment: How would you suppose the user program 'directly tries to access the disk' ?   How would that be expressed?

Comment: I presume the device driver is just executing some CPU instruction to write to the disk or signal the disk, what If user program just executes that instruction directly? How does OS guarantee safety ?

Comment: On x86, I/O ports can be restricted to ring 0, and I/O address space need not be included in ring 3 address space. So there is no instruction that user mode can execute that addresses the device. This is the fundamental aspect of the kernel/user split on any hardware: the kernel can control what user mode can do.

Comment: Thank you! I just happened to read the chapter on IO ports in Linux device drivers book, so I understand your statement. However, I have a question — what mandates user program use IO ports to write to device? Why cannot user program just by pass OS and IO ports and implement the logic of IO port function in user space program itself? Also, is it not possible to use DMA and bypass OS and CPU both?

Comment: Any piece of I/O hardware, such as the disk controller, will (designer's choice) either respond to an I/O port address or a memory-space address. There is no other way to talk to the hardware.  Since the kernel controls access to both I/O ports and physical memory-space addresses, it can absolutely remove access from user mode.

Comment: Maybe I should make an answer from all these comments...

Comment: Yes please do. This is very insightful. I can credit you for that answer then

Comment: *"How does the OS intercept it?"* -- It doesn't.  It is the CPU (i.e. hardware) that detects the execution of an improper instruction by user mode.  The OS (i.e. software) is then responsible for handling the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any piece of I/O hardware, such as the disk controller, will (designer's choice) either respond to an I/O port address or a memory-space address, or possibly both.  There is no other way to talk to the hardware. The hardware is sitting out on some bus.  Program code must read/write some I/O port or must read/write some "memory" address which is really the device rather than actual RAM.

On x86, since the kernel controls access to both:

- I/O ports, by setting or not setting the I/O port permissions, preventing ring 3 access
- physical memory-space addresses (by controlling the virtual-to-physical address mapping)

then it can absolutely remove access from user mode.

So there is no instruction that user mode can execute that addresses the device. This is the fundamental aspect of the kernel/user split on any hardware: the kernel can control what user mode can do.

To pick up on a comment by @sawdust - once the kernel has set up the above restrictions, then:

- an attempt to issue an I/O port instruction will trap to the kernel because access has not been granted.
- access to memory-space device addresses is simply inexpressible; there is no user-space virtual address that equates to the particular physical address required.

Comment: Thanks. But what about DMA? Does it not allow program to bypass the CPU? I thought bypassing was the whole point of DMA for performance improvements.

Comment: DMA transfers data without CPU involvement, but you first have to tell the device to transfer the data - which you have no way to do.  Disks don't just up and decide they feel like transferring data.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Is there a good book or article to understand this in depth?